# csvgrep from csvkit search multiple strings

Tags: csv, csvkit

Looking at the docs for csvgrep https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/csvgrep.html

I don't inherently see a way to search for multiple strings? Am I missing something?

```
csvgrep -c 1 -m "test" -m " test2" file.csv | csvlook | less -s
```

Comment: have you tried this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936421/757714

Answer (score 0):

you must use regex syntax

```
csvgrep -c 1 -r '(test1|test2)' input.csv | csvlook | less -s
```